# Python Java - wrong class file version when calling a JAR from Python script with subprocess.Popen

Tags: java, python

I have a java program compiled with jdk13, and installed jdk13 on the server running it. If I run the program from the commandline, there are no problems, however when I call it from my python script with subprocess.Popen, I get this error message in stderr

```
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

How can this happen through the python script and not when I run it manually in the commandline?

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your python script might be using a different environment where `java` means something different (id est, points to a different executable).

Try call directly you can find in your command line with `which java`.

Comment: doing java -version in the commandline gives me the correct version 13

Comment: as suggested by Stephen in the other answer, also check your `CLASSPATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables. Also check that you are in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

> How can this happen through the python script and not when I run it manually in the commandline?

Basically, the version of java that is used with depend on:

- the full pathname that you use; e.g. `/usr/bin/java` or
- the `PATH` environment variable if you are launching it with a simple command name; e.g. `java`.

We can't see what your python script is doing, but there are a number of ways that you could get different behavior.

1. The script could be using a different full pathname for `java`.
2. Python or your python script could be overriding `PATH`.
3. You could be launching your python script via a shell script that is setting `PATH` differently.  Note that shell initialization is rather complicated, and typically it sets up `PATH` depending on what init files get run.
4. If you are using `sudo`, that overrides `PATH`.
5. The `PATH` setting in your command prompt could have been set "by hand".

And that is just some of the *more likely* possibilities ...